# SQL Server 2008 R2 in Hyper-V does not the see the host HDD partition mapped as Vistual Disk

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I need help with this problems discussed as follows:

- I have created Gen-1 Hyper-VM on Windows 10 Pro 64 and it is    networked and shows all host PC and can connect to internet.
- I installed SQL Server R2 on it with the idea of connecting to
  databases residing on one of host partitioned (SSD)

[image]

- I then configured that host PC partition drive with SQL databases on
  it as Virtual Drive successfully and I tested it both way
  communication successfully. (Figure-1)
- Now, when I try to attach the database from VM to that drive, SQL
  server does not show that drive in the list of drives (Figure-2)

I am scratching my head as to what am I missing here. I would appreciate any suggestion here.